# Page fragment efficiency [Android Development]

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-styles

Is it better to destroy a tab's page fragment when the user swipes to a different tab, and then recreate the fragment when the user swipes back to it? Or is it better to `hide` it (maintain in memory) and `show` when needed again?

On the computer, I wouldn't think twice, but because this is mobile hardware, I thought it was important to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It's better destroy it, you could provoke a lack of memory.

Or you can try saving the status from the swiped tab.